# Centering unordered list inside container-fluid in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am currently trying to center an unordered list inside of my bootstrap application. Currently, I tried a solution using flex but could not get the elements to move. The application reads like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="keyboardJS">
       <%Call KeyBoardJS()%>
      </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
</div>
```

The ASP function `KeyboardJS()` is merely a bunch of html code that creates a virtual keyboard, the keyboard is aligned in the way I want it to, but the markup around it does not give me the correct spacing:

[image]

How would I go about centering the keyboard div? I have tried:

```
<style>
    #keyboardJS div {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

And even

```
<style>
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
</style>
```

But neither solution works. Pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bootstrap grids to center it.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"> 
      <%Call KeyBoardJS()%>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it disrupts the way in which the keyboard looks like, something that I tried doing was giving the container-fluid an inline style with padding-left and setting a value, that works but it takes away the responsiveness in terms of screen resizing.

Comment: Okay, if the inline style you added worked then add responsive css to also adjust for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If `<%Call KeyBoardJS()%>` spits out a bunch of html code whose parent is `#keyboardJS`, then the right code to center it with flex will be:

```
 #keyboardJS {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

Give it a try, or even better provide a live example (Fiddle, Plunker, Pen, etc.).